# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors Consisting of A and the Inverse of A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the following, assume that there is a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.

Under this assumption,

How do the eigenvalues of $A$ compare with the eigenvalues of $A^2$?

If $A$ is also an invertible matrix, how do the eigenvalues of $A$ compare with the eigenvalues of $A^{−1}$?

Comment: So your matrix is diagonalizable. Take $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}=D$, with $D$ a diagonal consisting of the eigenvalues of $A$. Then compute $A^2$ and $A^{-1}$. What happens to $D$?

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable, then the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$. Same for when $A$ is invertible and diagonalizable -- the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are the inverses of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
Ax&=\lambda x\\
AAx&=\lambda Ax\\ 
A^2x&=\lambda (\lambda x)\\
A^2x&=\lambda^2 x\\
\end{align}

Assuming $A^{-1}$ exists,
\begin{align}
Ax&=\lambda x\\
A^{-1}Ax&=\lambda A^{-1}x\\
Ix&=\lambda A^{-1}x\\
A^{-1}x&=\dfrac{1}{\lambda} Ix\\
A^{-1}x&=\dfrac{1}{\lambda} x\\
\end{align}